# Установка старой версии chrome на ubunty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome

Есть машина на ubunty 20 Хочу установить на нее chrome 114.0.5735.90, возможна ли установка старой версии, на просторах интернета ответов не нашел

Comment: Видимо, как-то [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54927497/3240681)

Comment: может докеровский образ есть?

Comment: Можно узнать - зачем?